# how to extract structured informaion from pdf file in java

Tags: java, pdf

I need to extract table from pdf file , i know it is not stored in table format but i want to read student result from pdf in java , please help if anyone knows.... thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use a PDF parser for that. Check out this [list of open source PDF libraries for Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries).

Comment: but how do these libraries parse for table (rows and columns) , i have used iText and pdfbox but could not find any help how they work for table ...

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing like a table in PDF. A table in PDF is composed of horizontal and vertical lines and for each cell a separate text-box.

Answer (score 3):

SOme PDF files contain PDF structured text (http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/09/the-easy-way-to-discover-if-a-pdf-file-contains-structured-content/). If they do not, it is down to the heuristics of the parser to guess this and add structure.

The PdfBox developers did a lot of work on tables but it will never be perfect

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Any suggestion in where to find that information?